# Recursion with large text file

Tags: python

I am trying to read in a large text file (1.08 MB with 116253 words) and I am running into a problem with the program stopping about 1/20th of the way into the text file (Stopping in the `Read` function and not even executing the `print` statement).

Here is the function as I have it now:

```
from binary_search_tree import BinarySearchTree
from tree_node import TreeNode
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(5000000)

MovieTree = BinarySearchTree()

def Read(filename):
    file = open('movieData.txt')
    for line in file:
        MovieTree[line.strip()] = line
        print(line)
    file.close()

Read('movieData.txt')
print(MovieTree)
```

The binary_search_tree and tree_node where given to me as this is a homework assignment so I am under the assumption that is works because it has been used before.

Does anyone have any idea as to what the problem is?

Binary Search Tree:

```
from tree_node import TreeNode

class BinarySearchTree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def length(self):
        return self.size

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.root.__iter__()

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns a string representation of the tree
           rotated 90 degrees counter-clockwise"""

        def strHelper(root, level):
            resultStr = ""
            if root:
                resultStr += strHelper(root.rightChild, level+1)
                resultStr += "| " * level
                resultStr += str(root.key) + "\n"
                resultStr += strHelper(root.leftChild, level+1)                
            return resultStr


        return strHelper(self.root, 0)


    def __contains__(self,key):
        if self._get(key,self.root):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def get(self,key):
        if self.root:
            res = self._get(key,self.root)
            if res:
                return res.payload
            else:
                return None
        else:
            return None

    def _get(self,key,currentNode):
        if not currentNode:
            return None
        elif currentNode.key == key:
            return currentNode
        elif key < currentNode.key:
            return self._get(key,currentNode.leftChild)
        else:
            return self._get(key,currentNode.rightChild)

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self.get(key) 

    def __setitem__(self,k,v):
        self.put(k,v)

    def put(self,key,val):
        if self.root:
            self._put(key,val,self.root)
        else:
            self.root = TreeNode(key,val)
        self.size = self.size + 1

    def _put(self,key,val,currentNode):
        if key < currentNode.key:
            if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
                self._put(key,val,currentNode.leftChild)
            else:
                currentNode.leftChild = TreeNode(key,val,
                                          parent=currentNode)
        else:
            if currentNode.hasRightChild():
                self._put(key,val,currentNode.rightChild)
            else:
                currentNode.rightChild = TreeNode(key,val,
                                          parent=currentNode)

    def delete(self,key):
      if self.size > 1:
          nodeToRemove = self._get(key,self.root)
          if nodeToRemove:
              self.remove(nodeToRemove)
              self.size = self.size-1
          else:
              raise KeyError('Error, key not in tree')
      elif self.size == 1 and self.root.key == key:
          self.root = None
          self.size = self.size - 1
      else:
          raise KeyError('Error, key not in tree')

    def __delitem__(self,key):
        self.delete(key)


    def remove(self,currentNode):
      if currentNode.isLeaf(): #leaf
        if currentNode == currentNode.parent.leftChild:
            currentNode.parent.leftChild = None
        else:
            currentNode.parent.rightChild = None
      elif currentNode.hasBothChildren(): #interior
        succ = currentNode.findSuccessor()
        succ.spliceOut()
        currentNode.key = succ.key
        currentNode.payload = succ.payload

      else: # this node has one child
        if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
          if currentNode.isLeftChild():
              currentNode.leftChild.parent = currentNode.parent
              currentNode.parent.leftChild = currentNode.leftChild
          elif currentNode.isRightChild():
              currentNode.leftChild.parent = currentNode.parent
              currentNode.parent.rightChild = currentNode.leftChild
          else:
              currentNode.replaceNodeData(currentNode.leftChild.key,
                                 currentNode.leftChild.payload,
                                 currentNode.leftChild.leftChild,
                                 currentNode.leftChild.rightChild)

        else:
          if currentNode.isLeftChild():
              currentNode.rightChild.parent = currentNode.parent
              currentNode.parent.leftChild = currentNode.rightChild
          elif currentNode.isRightChild():
              currentNode.rightChild.parent = currentNode.parent
              currentNode.parent.rightChild = currentNode.rightChild
          else:
              currentNode.replaceNodeData(currentNode.rightChild.key,
                                 currentNode.rightChild.payload,
                                 currentNode.rightChild.leftChild,
                                 currentNode.rightChild.rightChild)
```

TreeNode:

```
class TreeNode:
   def __init__(self,key,val,left=None,right=None,
                                       parent=None):
      self.key = key
      self.payload = val
      self.leftChild = left
      self.rightChild = right
      self.parent = parent

   def hasLeftChild(self):
      return self.leftChild

   def hasRightChild(self):
      return self.rightChild

   def isLeftChild(self):
      return self.parent and \
             self.parent.leftChild == self

   def isRightChild(self):
      return self.parent and \
             self.parent.rightChild == self

   def isRoot(self):
      return not self.parent

   def isLeaf(self):
      return not (self.rightChild or self.leftChild)

   def hasAnyChildren(self):
      return self.rightChild or self.leftChild

   def hasBothChildren(self):
      return self.rightChild and self.leftChild

   def replaceNodeData(self,key,value,lc,rc):
      self.key = key
      self.payload = value
      self.leftChild = lc
      self.rightChild = rc
      if self.hasLeftChild():
          self.leftChild.parent = self
      if self.hasRightChild():
          self.rightChild.parent = self

   def __iter__(self):

      if self:
         if self.hasLeftChild():
              for elem in self.leftChild:
                 yield elem
         yield self.key
         if self.hasRightChild():
              for elem in self.rightChild:
                 yield elem

   def findSuccessor(self):
      succ = None
      if self.hasRightChild():
          succ = self.rightChild.findMin()
      else:
          if self.parent:
              if self.isLeftChild():
                  succ = self.parent
              else:
                  self.parent.rightChild = None
                  succ = self.parent.findSuccessor()
                  self.parent.rightChild = self
      return succ

   def findMin(self):
      current = self
      while current.hasLeftChild():
          current = current.leftChild
      return current

   def spliceOut(self):
      if self.isLeaf():
         if self.isLeftChild():
            self.parent.leftChild = None
         else:
            self.parent.rightChild = None
      elif self.hasAnyChildren():
         if self.hasLeftChild():
            if self.isLeftChild():
               self.parent.leftChild = self.leftChild
            else:
               self.parent.rightChild = self.leftChild
            self.leftChild.parent = self.parent
         else:
            if self.isLeftChild():
               self.parent.leftChild = self.rightChild
            else:
               self.parent.rightChild = self.rightChild
            self.rightChild.parent = self.parent
```

Comment: 1.08 Mb is not large.

Comment: Why does it stop?  Does it throw an exception? -- As it's written, we can't tell that it's actually using recursion at all.  Where does that fit into this picture?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code, unless you're using binary_tree_node or tree_node incorrectly...

Comment: @mgilson no there is no exception given it just stops. The two classes import will be added here in a second.

Comment: I believe I figured out the problem. It seems to be adding each movie title as it is an entire line. Thus making each element a child of the previous element which is making my BinarySearchTree to large and making it essentially a linked list.

I will fix this by splitting up the lines into words making for example 'A' the root note and so on. Which like Wai Yip Tung said should make my level size to around 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.08 MB is a small file. Why do you want to use BinarySearchTree? You can easily handle this by dumping the data into a dictionary.

If BinarySearchTree is part of the assignment, it looks to me it has bug. I'd start tracing from its _put() method.

By the way you should not use `sys.setrecursionlimit(5000000)` to get around the problem. A decent binary search will not hit this limit unless the size of your data is in the order of magnitude of 2^5000000. For the 116253 words that you have a balanced binary tree should only need 12 level of recursion.

Comment: The BinarySearchTree method is required, and yes the recursionlimit increase isn't. I think I figured out my problem though as everything is being added as a left child of the previous parent and it isn't branching it out and balancing it.

Answer (score 1):

Crashes here too with a stack-overflow.

Since your code doesn't contain recursion it must be within the classes your teacher gave you. I think the overflow happens in the `put(self, key, val)` method.

I'm afraid I barely know Python so I can't give you any futher help.